# How to use group by clause in ODI 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-data-integrator

```
SELECT PERIOD,
       PRODUCT_ID,
       MONTH,TARIFF_ID,
       SUM(QUANTITY) 
FROM billing_geneva_active_lines
GROUP BY PERIOD,
      PRODUCT_ID,
      MONTH,
      TARIFF_ID;
```

in `SQL` developer its getting executed but in `ODI 11g` how to write the same query?

Comment: In this query what you face an issue ?

Comment: @Prince__I was able to execute the same query in SQL but my question was how I have to write the same query in oracle data integrator 11g.

Comment: According to me it is also working in oracle data integrator 11g. If you find any issues while execute it then let us know so that we can solve it.

Comment: It worked for me after using the aggregate function -Sum(Quantity) to the target mapping for one attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the target mapping for one attribute – *QUANTITY* – and add aggregate function – *SUM(QUANTITY)* – to the target mapping for one attribute. ODI will automatically include all the attributes that don't have an aggregate function in the GROUP BY clause.

ODI 12c gives a bit more control by allowing you to write your own GROUP BY clause if you wish.

Comment: Thank you.. that was helpfull .